# Python cannot import DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use Pandas in Python to import and manipulate some csv file.

my code is like:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import dataframe  
data_df = pd.read_csv('highfrequency2.csv')
print(data_df.columns)
```

But there is an error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame
```

I have Pandas in Python, and I think dataframe comes with Pandas.

So, anyone can tell me what does this error message mean ?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that python imports are case sensitive. Your import line should be `from pandas import DataFrame`.  Also note that in your snippet you do not use this import, so you could leave it out.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're running? `from pandas import dataframe ` wouldn't give you `ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame`...

Comment: Did you actually see an ImportError with that capitalization of "DataFrame"?

Comment: @TristanSun Btw. please accept answers if they solved your issue.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use it exactly with '**DataFrame**' this is really important to pay attention to the upper and lowercase characters

```
import pandas as pd
data_df = pd.DataFrame('highfrequency2.csv')
print(data_df.columns)
```

Comment: thanks, but this time I capitalize the command 'DataFrame'. The error still shows 'ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame'

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do all necessary imports for using data frames with `pandas`.

Most people prefer this import: `import pandas as pd`. This imports `pandas` as an alias named `pd`. Then they can use `pd.DataFrame` instead of the rather verbose `pandas.DataFrame` they had to write if they just used `import pandas`.

This would be a typical code example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [3, 2, 1]}
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Of course you can pull `DataFrame` into your namespace directly. You would then go with `from pandas import DataFrame`. Note that python imports are case sensitive:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [3, 2, 1]}
data_df = DataFrame(data)
```

Also be aware that you only have to import `DataFrame` if you intend to call it directly. `pd.read_csv` e.g. will always return a `DataFrame` object for you. To use it you don't have to explicitly import `DataFrame` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
import pandas as pd
data_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

or This should work `from pandas import DataFrame` as module name is 'DataFrame' and it is case-sensitive.