# How to extract a particular values from a txt file and make those all into df

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

have a txt file contains many values

Used regex

```
'many_espd': '(\d+)'
```

This gets my requirement but how to take all those values and make it a df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this option, which creates a single column data frame from your list of matching digits:

```
result_list = re.findall(r"'many_espd': '(\d+)'", text)
df = DataFrame({'espd': result_list})
```

Note that if you are actually using regex to parse JSON content, then stop here, and instead look into using a JSON parser.

Comment: sure will look into that.

Comment: Please [read this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729185/python-cannot-import-dataframe) to see how to correct import data frame into Python.